# PCI-ring which is not semisimple .

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra, injective-module

Is there an example of finite right(left) PCI-ring which is not right(left) semisimple ring?
(A ring R is called right(left) PCI-ring if each proper right(left) cyclic R-module C is injective, proper cyclic means that C is cyclic but C is not isomorphic to R).

Answer (score 2):

By the Faith-Cozzens theorem, if it is not semisimple, then it is simple (and right Hereditary and right Ore and a $V$-domain.) But a finite and simple ring is semisimple. So, no, there is no such finite ring.

> Thanks for answering. May I know if there exist a commutative PCI-ring not semisimple ring.

No: a commutative $V$- ring is Von Neumann regular, and a commutative VNR domain is a field.

Comment: Thanks for answering. May I know if there exist a commutative PCI-ring not semisimple ring.

Comment: @MManhal added this to the answer. If I remember right, the examples of nonsemisimple PCI rings are fairly rare.